# USRP E312 how to find connected gps antenna

Tags: usrp

On the USRP E312, how can I find the connected gps antenna? Will it pop up in dmesg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "find" it. It's not a device in the linux kernel sense.

It's simply the antenna used by the built-in GPS module to receive GPS; you don't "see" it under linux, just like you don't "see" the Antenna that you attach to your e.g. Wifi card (you see that *card*, though).

This question reeks very very much of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info); please feel very invited to ask a new question (please don't do that in the comments!) that describes the actual *problem* you're trying to solve.